# JSP popup message on mouseover not working

Tags: jsp, popup, mouseover, mouseout

In a jsp page I am trying to popup a window when mouse is over some text. So I am trying to use mouseover

```
<TD> <a id="hoverover" onmouseover="ShowPopup();" onmouseout=HidePopup();>Hover over me!</a> </TD>
```

inside an array.

AFTER I DISABLED the popup-blocking from firefox, I still see nothing on mouseover.. :-(

Comment: There might be an error occuring in the ShowPopup() or HidePopup() methods.  The "onmouseout"  is missing quotes.. that can't be good.

Comment: Try to test by doing:   onmouseover="alert('Hello');"